# Is there a way to sort in SAS where the output displays only one unique column?

Tags: sas

I am trying to group my SAS code by showing only the results that display one specified 'REGION' and one specified 'POL' Column. I am able to do this by using the where clause however, it seems that it doesn't show only REGION and POL once. it shows them 'n' times.

this is what is looks like: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3x2I.png)

This is what I want:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os2sT.png)

Here is my code:

```
proc sort data = pojects;
by REGION POL;
run;

proc print data = projects;
var REGION POL_TYPE;
WHERE REGION = "1";
Where POL_TYPE = "X";
RUN;
```

Comment: You already have an answer, but since you're new to SAS, wanted to point out that it is critical to read the SAS log carefully.  The log from the code you have written has a NOTE in it: `"NOTE: WHERE clause has been replaced."` This tells you the statement `WHERE REGION = "1";` is being ignored because it has been replaced by the statement `Where POL_TYPE = "X";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get PROC PRINT to display something like your second photograph you can use the BY and ID statements.  Also to combine your filtering conditions either use one WHERE with a complex condition or you can use WHERE ALSO to add additional filtering conditions.

```
proc print data = projects;
  by REGION POL_TYPE;
  id REGION POL_TYPE;
  WHERE REGION = "1" and POL_TYPE = "X";
RUN;
```

Or switch to using PROC REPORT and have a lot more control over what the report looks like.